# Give SO the same design as pt.SO

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, design

I just took a look at pt.SO and noticed the design is slightly different.

Will SO get the same design? I must say I like it, it feels less heavy.

[image: pt.SO]
[image: SO]

Comment: OMG change the design? *But the new design hurts my eyes. I can't work like that. Change is bad. Oh the horror. SO/SE should hire a designer. Rant boo blah.*

Comment: I kinda like SO proper's design better, TBH.

Comment: I like the code on pt better, otherwise SO seems better.

Comment: That's the same font size that Code Review uses for their code samples.

Comment: I'm hoping that the subtle design changes on Stack Overflow PT are just "testing it out" to see how it works before pushing it to main where there's a much larger audience. I like all the changes on the PT theme. For those wondering: the pagination at the bottom is different, and the tags don't have a box-shadow. Some of my custom user-scripts may be hiding other changes.

Comment: @animuson I can neither confirm nor deny that this is [Jin's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) secret plan